# How to open url from popup, in the parent window

Tags: javascript

I'm using a drupal module that allows me to show in a popup some html code and of course I can include a javascript. To understand what kind of popups I'm talking about, simply visit the module page [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/splashify)

The script allows me to redirect the user, after the end of the countdown, to an external URL address, example.com

There is only a small hitch:

example.com is displayed inside the popup itself, I would like it to be opened in the current browser tab.

I tried to replace `window.location` with `window.open` but this way example.com is not displayed at all. However in the Chrome DevTools JavaScript Console I don't see any message.

Using `window.location.href` the page is still opened inside the popup

Using `window.opener.location` example.com is not displayed at all. This is the error in the Console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'location' of null
    at countdown (splashify-splash:13)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

This is the HTML code:

```html
<!-- Modify this according to your requirement -->
<h3>
  Redirecting to example.com after <span id="countdown">10</span> seconds
</h3>
<!-- JavaScript part -->
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Total seconds to wait
    var seconds = 10;

    function countdown() {
        seconds = seconds - 1;
        if (seconds < 0) {
            // Chnage your redirection link here
            window.location = "https://example.com";
        } else {
            // Update remaining seconds
            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = seconds;
            // Count down using javascript
            window.setTimeout("countdown()", 1000);
        }
    }

    // Run countdown function
    countdown();

</script>
```

Comment: Please explain what _exactly_ you actually mean by “popup”. A new window opened using window.open, a modal using an iframe, …?

Comment: Try with `window.location.href` ..

Comment: @dimitris-efst does not work!

Comment: @04FS it's a modal. See colorbox module for Drupal

Comment: So it uses an iframe then? Then `parent.location.href = ...` or `top.location.href = ...` should do the trick.

Comment: @04FS now it works the way I wanted! you are great!

Comment: @04FS to open a link to the parent location is it necessary to use javascript or is it also possible to do with an html attribute?

Comment: Sure, the `target` attribute works pretty much the same way - only the reserved window names are prefixed with a `_` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This modal component seems to display content inside an iframe, so to break out of that either target the parent of that iframe, or the top window instance:

```
parent.location.href = ...
```

or

```
top.location.href = ...
```

`parent` refers to the window instance immediately above the iframe, `top` is always the outermost window instance. If you only have one “level” of iframe-ing going on, both will refer to the same object, in case of nested frames that would be different.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 
window.opener.location="example.com";

This will open the URL in the parent window.

Comment: could you please share me the snippet of code you are writing??

Comment: now the page is not even displayed, and also produces an error in the console!

Comment: I would like to see the code, you previously wrote. The snippet you added does not open pop up.

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear. the javascript code does not open a popup.
is the drupal module that opens the popup.
then, from the module, I set that HTML code (including JavaScript) to open in the popup.

Comment: In Drupal what is the module you installed to generate popup? Is it a modal or popup window?

Comment: In this case, you cannot do the thing as it a modal, not a different popup window.